# How can i Update inventory using TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Well here is the problem...I want to update the inventory table at my database which includes

```
Sale(ProductID,Quantity,Price)                 
Invlevel(ProductID,Quantity)
```

I want to use triggers for this update. I have to use 2 triggers (I think). 1 at the sale tables which will be something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER `sale_AINS` AFTER INSERT ON sale FOR EACH ROW
begin
update Invlevel set quantity = Invlevel.quantity-"sale.quantity" where
Invlevel.ProductID = "sale.ProductID";
END
```

with this trigger, when a sale comes up, I want to adjust the inventory level at the product which the sale came to. However, even though this trigger has no errors and runs properly when I insert into sale table, it doesn't make any changes at the Invlevel table and I don't know why ( :@ ).

Moreover, I made the trigger at the Invlevel table like that

```
CREATE TRIGGER `invlevel_AUPD` after UPDATE on invlevel FOR EACH ROW
if invlevel.quantity < 20 
begin
insert into orders 
(select productid,amount from reorder where reorder.productid = invlevel.productid )
end
```

*(orders,reorder are other tables)

It says to me I have syntax error which I don't know what it is and also even if I find it I can't even check the logic because the other trigger isn't even working... Any thought or help about it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

First trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER sale_AINS
AFTER INSERT ON sale 
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE invlevel 
     SET quantity = quantity - NEW.quantity
   WHERE productid = NEW.productid;
```

*In this trigger you don't need `BEGIN END` block since there is only one statement. In order to access column values or a row(s) that being inserted you need to use `NEW` keyword.*

And the second one

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER invlevel_AUPD
AFTER UPDATE ON invlevel 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.quantity < 20 THEN 
    INSERT INTO orders (productid, amount)
    SELECT productid, amount 
      FROM reorder 
     WHERE productid = NEW.productid;
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

*In the second trigger `IF` statement was out of `BEGIN END` block and syntax for `IF` was wrong. It should be `IF ... THEN ... END IF;`. And the same problems with a `NEW` keyword.*

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e09a7a/2)** demo

You can put your `IF` condition into `WHERE` clause and make it more succinct like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER invlevel_AUPD
AFTER UPDATE ON invlevel 
FOR EACH ROW
  INSERT INTO orders (productid, amount)
  SELECT productid, amount 
    FROM reorder 
   WHERE productid = NEW.productid
     AND NEW.quantity < 20;
```

Here is updated **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ed86/1)** demo